# OTRS : Create Outgoing E-Mail-Ticket via Webservice

Tags: php, rest, guzzle, otrs

I am trying to create an Ticket via PHP & the REST genericinterface from OTRS (https://doc.otrs.com/doc/manual/admin/6.0/en/html/genericinterface.html#id-1.6.12.10.7.2).

I can create an Ticket and also an Article. But instead of an outgoing email the OTRS History looks like the user was sending a ticket to the queue. And also no mail is going out to the customer :-(.
But I like to have an outgoing EMail Ticket together with a pending state of the ticket.

[image: OTRS Picture]

Here my PHP code

```
<?php
header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use GuzzleHttp\Client;

$client = new Client(['base_uri' => 'http://test-otrs.company.local/otrs/nph-genericinterface.pl/Webservice/GenericTicketConnectorREST/']);

$arrTicket = array(
    "Title"        => 'some ticket title',
    "Queue"        => 'testqueue',
    "Lock"         => 'unlock',
    "Type"         => 'Unclassified',
    "State"        => 'new',
    "Priority"     => '3 normal',
    "Owner"        => 'username',
    "CustomerUser" => 'user@test.com'
);

$arrArticle = array(
    "CommunicationChannel"  => 'Email',
    "SenderType"            => 'agent',
    "To"                    => 'user@test.com',
    "Subject"               => 'some subject',
    "Body"                  => 'some body',
    "ContentType"           => 'text/plain; charset=utf8'
);

$response = $client->post('Ticket', ['json' => array("UserLogin" => "username", "Password" => "testtesttest", "Ticket" => $arrTicket, "Article" => $arrArticle)]);

if ($response->getBody())
    {
    echo $response->getBody();
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: What I did: Trying to find working PHP examples (could not find some). Switching To/From Keys. Try different SenderType and CommunicationChannels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://forums.otterhub.org/viewtopic.php?p=168025#p168025 solved my problem. You need a extra plugin (https://github.com/znuny/Znuny4OTRS-GIArticleSend) to be able to send an outgoing EMail Ticket.